# Jquery.Change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble with $.change in jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
<p id="chg" class="change">Click Me</p>
<div class="onchange"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Click Me');
  $('.onchange').text('');
});
$('.change').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Nearly There');
});
$('.change').on('change', function() {
  $('.onchange').text("Nice One");
});
```

Here is the link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/richardmountain/pen/aOXzMB)

Basically what should happen is when "Click Me" is clicked the text will change to "Nearly There" then straight after "Nice One" should appear below.

However this isn't happening, I've tried both

```
$('.change').on('change', function() {});
$('.change').change(function() {});
```

And neither work.

**Note**
The code I have supplied is my test code, and is all relevant to what I'm trying to achieve.

**Update**
I wasn't aware the .change only worked for form controls, which would explain why it wasn't working.

**Solution**
CreMedian - Suggested the solution that I was looking for.

```
$('.change').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() { });
```

I have updated the CodePen for future reference.

Comment: `.change` is only for form elements. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Note that the change event only fires on `input`, `select` and `texarea` elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: Why would you need your last function at all? When you click change and change its text, just also change the text of the onchange div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the `.change()` event does not work with div elements.

One way you could get the same effect is with the following code:

```
$('.change').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  //action you want when the '.change' object changes
});
```

Javascript `MutationEvent` is not widely supported, so be careful if implementing this in production code.

Reference Link: http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.change').on('change', function() {
```

in your example, `.change` is a div, and divs dont raise change events when clicked.

You probably wanted to just update both elements from the `click` event

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Click Me');
  $('.onchange').text('');
});
$('.change').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Nearly There');
  $('.onchange').text("Nice One");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just to clarify I want the second text to update when a change is detected in the first text.

Comment: But you're changing the first text yourself, just change the second text too :S Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's more about the .change value than whether the button is clicked, as I have updated the op, this was just a test set up, the live site I'm working on the .change value can be modified from multiple locations on the page so it is easier to check for the .change value rather than checking whether a button has been pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`DOMSubtreeModified`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php) event.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Click Me');
  $('.onchange').text('');
});
$('.change').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Nearly There');
});
$('.change').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  $('.onchange').text("Nice One");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
<p id="chg" class="change">Click Me</p>
<div class="onchange"></div>
```

**Note:** It will not supported by IE8 and older.

Demo in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdzdWb)

Comment: Cool, didn't know this existed.

Comment: Ah! yes, will be triggered whenever DOM changes.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
$('.change').text('Nearly There').trigger('change');
```

example

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Click Me');
  $('.onchange').text('');
});
$('.change').on('click', function() {
  $('.change').text('Nearly There').trigger('change');
});
$('.change').on('change', function() {
  $('.onchange').text("Nice One");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Reset</button>
<p id="chg" class="change">Click Me</p>
<div class="onchange"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, plus using trigger to trigger the change event on a paragraph still won't work.

Comment: @j08691 it worked exactly as OP described in codepen

Comment: You're not understanding the issue. `$('.change').on('change', function() {` won't (and can't) work.

Comment: This wouldn't work for what I'm looking for, the text in .change could and will change randomly there would be no way to trigger it based on the text value.

Answer (score 0):

The browser only fires `change` events for `textbox`, `check/radio box` and `select list` - all form elements. When something changes within your `<div>` or `<p>`, the browser does nothing to notify your javascript. Therefore, the listener `.on('change'` is not going to ever fire.

Here is a short lists of for elements that raise the event:

- **TextBox**  When Enter key is pressed
- **Radio/Check** Box  When the state is changed
- **Select List**  When the selected item is changed

Here is more on the event: [Mozilla MDN onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange)